# how to convert integer [70] in to [.70]?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

How to convert a whole number into decimal..For example 70 to .70
because there are some price in my system that needed to be calculated by grams
for example $5 per grams...
I am saving the price in my database as an integer..

Thank's for dropping by

Comment: why not save price as it should be, as money?

Comment: You could divide it by `100`?

Comment: Surely you mean divide by `100.0`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use vb for a long time, but, I guess, simple float division will work

```
Dim number As Integer
Dim result As Decimal

number = 70
result = number / 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing cents and you want to display dollars divide the cents from the database by 100 and show that number in the user interface.

If the user enters an amount of dollars (and cents) multiply by 100 before storing in the database.